# Installing Cairo and PyCairo Mac OsX

Tags: igraph, cairo, pycairo

I am playing around with using python iGraph for network visualization. I got his error message when I tried to plot a graph:

```
>>> layout = g.layout("kk")
>>> plot(g, layout = layout)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/igraph/drawing/__init__.py", line 446, in plot
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/igraph/drawing/__init__.py", line 117, in __init__
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-x86_64/egg/igraph/drawing/utils.py", line 396, in __getattr__
TypeError: plotting not available
```

I don't think I installed Cairo or PyCairo correctly.

I am not familiar using Fink or MacPorts, since I commonly use Homebrew.

Any help you be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

You need to manually compile the library. I used the solution [here](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/wiki/Installation---OSX) and just updated the version.

```
curl -L https://www.cairographics.org/releases/cairo-1.14.6.tar.xz -o cairo.tar.xz
tar -xf cairo.tar.xz && cd cairo-1.14.6
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --disable-dependency-tracking
make install
```

If while running configure, you get an error about pkg_config, you can install that with brew:

```
brew install pkg-config
```

Comment: Is there a way to install it without using brew?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on my MacBook so I wanted to share my solution.

I tried to install `pycairo`, `py2cairo`. The installation seemed to be okay but then:

1. I could not `import pycairo`
2. igraph's plot would not work.

The following solved the igraph plotting issue:

```
sudo pip install cairocffi
```

or just

```
pip install cairocffi
```

So instead of pycairo I used cairocffi and this did the trick.

Comment: This answer also works for me, but just adding that `cairocffi`depends on cairo, which can be installed on mac using: `brew install cairo` (see [here](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/cairo))

Answer (score 0):

As Mads said in a comment, `brew install cairo` works, it solved a related problem for me, so I'm posting here for people who end up here why troubleshooting cairo on OS X.

Accepted answer lead to an error of `libpng` missing, homebrew on the other hand installed all dependencies correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I first used homebrew to install cairo and pkg-config. Then used pip to install pycairo.

```
brew install cairo pkg-config
pip3 install pycairo
```

This installed pycairo correctly.