# OSError: no library called "cairo" error even after installing macports

Tags: python-3.7, macos-big-sur, django-2.2

I'm getting this error when trying to start the Django server by using the python manage.py runserver command.

```
OSError: no library called "cairo" was found
no library called "libcairo-2" was found
cannot load library 'libcairo.so.2': dlopen(libcairo.so.2, 2): image not found
cannot load library 'libcairo.2.dylib': dlopen(libcairo.2.dylib, 2): image not found
cannot load library 'libcairo-2.dll': dlopen(libcairo-2.dll, 2): image not found
```

I'm using python 3.7, django==2.2.5, and Mac BigSur version 11.0.1.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60926387/9568847) help you? (`pip install cairocffi`)

Comment: Else please specify what you are trying to do, what code exactly causes the error and how you tried to fix it. Django does not require cairo by itself.

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem? I am facing the exact same problem after migrating to Big Sur, also using the exact same versions of everything, all the dependencies where installed and the exact same packages where installed from the requirements.txt file i was working in my previous pc.

Comment: I'm also finding this trying to use Weasyprint.

Comment: @TonyHorrocks I am facing the same exact issue while using WeasyPrint on Mac M1. Are you able to find any solution?

Comment: Not yet! Using 11.5.2 Bug Sur

Comment: @SuloveBista Same issue using Macbook pro M1. I am trying to import cairosvg .

Comment: I have found a solution for Mac M1 while installing weasyprint, have commented in the answer. have a look, might be of help to you @TonyHorrocks

Answer (score 3):

You can solve the problem as follows.

- Create links or aliases to other files on your Unix system from the current folder to libcairo in **/opt/homebrew/lib/libcairo.2.dylib** using the command below.

  `ln -s /opt/homebrew/lib/libcairo.2.dylib .`
- Then execute the command again.

It should work without any problems.

Answer (score -1):

For Mac M1, I was facing this issue while trying to install weasyprint and it got solved by downgrading the version of weasyprint to 53.3.